# How to get table , ID information from Scala Slick Query object

Tags: scala, slick, sharding, typesafe

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]

val query = for( user <- Users.filter(_.id === 1L) ) yield user

println(query.toNode.nodeChildNames.toBuffer)

gives something like this  => ArrayBuffer(from @1276230271, select)
```

How to get user id information from above query at runtime. What if query is more complex like

```
val query = for( user <- users.filter(_name === "cat")

                 post < posts.filter(_.postedBy === user.id)

                 comment <- comments.filter(_.postId === post.id) ) yield comment
```

From the above query can we access table names and primary keys involved in each query dynamically using access to Query object .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to yield a tuple (post.id, user.id, comment.id), e.g.:

```
val query = for{ user <- users.filter(_name === "cat")
                 post <- posts.filter(_.postedBy === user.id)
                 comment <- comments.filter(_.postId === post.id) }
            yield (post.id, user.id, comment.id)

query.list
```

Comment: sorry ... i have not clearly conveyed by problem in the question. i have changed the question now Please consider re answering the question. Thanks